# Why can I not see revision history of shared Google Docs documents?

Tags: google-docs, sharing

My friend shared a document with me on Google Docs. The document was then edited, and is now at revision 2.

How do I view revision 1?

[image: file menu of google docs]

For some reason I cannot click "see revision history".

Are there other solutions I could do? Like "revert my Google Docs state to 1 day before" or something like that?

Comment: I had the same issue. Problem solved when I switched to Chrome and logged into my Google account.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If the **See revision history** is greyed out or you can't select it, the document you are viewing does not allow you to edit and hence, you can't see the revision history.

This is usually the case when the owner of the document has set you to either:

- Can comment
- Can view

To be able to see the revision history your permissions on the document must be either of the two:

- Is owner
- Can edit

Answer (score 6):

Even if you have Edit permission, sometimes the **File -> "See revision history"** menu option is grey-out. I've seen this happen after the page has been loaded in a tab for a long time.

In this situation, reloading the Chrome tab for the Sheet has restored the Revision History menu option.

Answer (score 1):

This also occurs when you use an incompatible browser. I used Mozilla and had the problem, switched to IE and it worked. Also, it never happened to be while using Chrome.